# How to output this to the screen?

Tags: java, arrays, output

I'm currently studying for my introductory CS final, and I'm having a really rough time with a few problems. The one I'm most worried about asks me to produce the code, in Java, to create the following output to the screen:

+

+++0

++++++00

++++++++++000

... (this pattern continues for 200 lines)

This might seem like a very basic question, but how do I go about doing this? I know that I should write some arrays and use for loops to go through them and output stuff to the screen, but I would really appreciate some guidance on how to solve this problem, along with others of its ilk. Thanks!

Comment: you dont need an array, all you need is a loop with some logic.

Comment: Is there 9 or 10 `+`' in the last part? because that actually makes a big difference in the pattern

Comment: In future try something yourself then post code here, logic must be yours SO will help to fix any error.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for the number of `0` is simply an arithmetic sequence. The number of `+` is as follows:

```
Row 1:  1
Row 2:  3 = 1 + 2
Row 3:  6 = 3 + 3
Row 4: 10 = 6 + 4
```

Turns out that these are [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). So, calculate the triangular number for each row in a loop, and have a nested loop that prints `+` that many times, then print the required number of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this deserves a -1. Beginner question is not equal to a bad question.

As for the question itself. You have to carefully identify the pattern first and then word it in plain English. The pattern is quite simple.

> Start with 1 cross and 0 zero. For each iteration, increase the growth
>   of crosses by 1 (so it's +1, +2, +3...) starting with a growth of 2
>   units and increase the growth of zeroes by 1 starting at 1 unit.

Now put this into pseudo-code and then code it. **Be sure to understand the patterns first**. I cannot stress this enough. Going right into coding will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be able to recogonize the pattern, then you need to be able to code it.

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that you are mixing the two "steps" of this problem together, so let's be very specific in dividing them.

```
The (parenthesis) items are the _additional_ elements.

index 0 : +
index 1 : +(++)(0)
index 2 : +++(+++)0(0)
index 3 : ++++++(++++)00(0)
```

so a good guess is that the pattern could be described as:

```
the previous number of +'s (and index + 1 more), 
followed by the previous number of 0's (and one more).
```

combined with

```
index 0 is "+"
```

You might want to calculate index 4, 5, and 6 from this "rule" and see if it seems to describe the pattern correctly.

Now that you have the pattern, you really only need two variables, the number of `+` signs, and the number of `0`s.  You can calculate the "next" one from the previous one.  The coding shouldn't be too hard, but if it is, then post your program and your "new" problem with that program in another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Answer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int plusCount = 1;
        for(int i=0; i<200; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<plusCount; j++) {
                System.out.write('+');
            }
            plusCount += i+2;
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
                System.out.write('0');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```